# How to show scrollbar on ScrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview, scrollbar

I have the following xml file -

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_terms_and_conditions_back_image"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow_left" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/fragment_terms_and_conditions_terms_and_conditions"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/main_app_top_margin_15dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions_fragment_overview"
                android:textColor="@color/color_light_gray"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/main_app_top_margin_15dp"
                android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions_fragment_overview_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@color/color_list_divider_color" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/main_app_top_margin_15dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions_fragment_terms_prohibited_use"
                android:textColor="@color/color_light_gray"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/main_app_top_margin_15dp"
                android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions_fragment_terms_prohibited_use_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@color/color_list_divider_color" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions_fragment_terms_post_sales_support"
                android:textColor="@color/color_light_gray"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/main_app_top_margin_15dp"
                android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions_fragment_terms_post_sales_support_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:background="@color/color_list_divider_color" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_bold"
                android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions_fragment_terms_illegal_distribution"
                android:textColor="@color/color_light_gray"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/main_app_top_margin_15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
                android:text="@string/terms_and_conditions_fragment_terms_illegal_distribution_content"
                android:textColor="@color/black" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

but the Scrollview does not show the scrollbar like the following picture -

[image]

I tried to add `android:fadeScrollbars="false"` and android:scrollbarFadeDuration="0" and nothing works

I tried also to put the fadescrollbars to true and add some durations to the fade and it does not have any effect

what am I missing?

Comment: add android:scrollbars="vertical" to your ScrollView

Comment: @Tinsel tried that, did not work.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? I copied your xml and filled in some dummy text, scrollbars are shown correctly. Scrollbars are not shown permanently, only when the user is scrolling. That's the standard behaviour...